# Autoreload webpage when source changed

Tags: python, django

I wonder is there some optional configuration to the dev server to autorefresh page when files changed. I know that django dev server autoreload project when some changes appear but what i am looking for is refreshing the webpage like it is in for example meteor. I was googling a little and find some apps and plugins to ff and chrome.

Django is designed to web development so i suspect that such feature should be in the core of dev server. Is it?

Comment: Can you please clarify the "like it is in for example meteor" part?

Comment: Django isn't a web server, its a web *framework*, its your deployments job to tell whatever is running your django instance to restart as needed

Answer (score 0):

No, dev server is just a simple server that accepts request, passes it to the django app and returns a response from the app. It is something different than you can find in some JavaScript libraries or frameworks, where data are held in browser and you only hot reload the source code and library regenerates the page using the same data.